# Drupal Advertisement Module

Tags: drupal, ads

We have a Drupal 6 website and we want to add Advertisements to the site. I had used OpenAds 7 years ago but now since they changed to openx, i can't quite understand from their website if it's still FREE to use with all the features that were available in OpenAds many years ago.

Roaming around i found Drupal Advertisement Module which seems to report the most installs (8200 people using it approx).

The question is if some has used this module and can tell me if it supports the industry standard methods for selling ads, i.e. are we able to do the following:

1. Sell space using CPM (Cost Per Matrix views).
2. Cost Per Click (CPC)
3. any others ....

Can we create accounts for different advertisers and specify the budget and the ads stop automatically when their views or clicks exceed their budget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can learn about the differences between OpenX products here: 
http://www.openx.com/publisher/compare-ad-server-products

Please let us know if there's anything we can do to help you out. You can email us here:  openxnews@openx.com